# Boletos.Net com .NET Core(v2.0) C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-cli

Estou tentando utilizar o BoletosNet para gerar um boleto e posteriormente um PDF do mesmo, mas quando tento utilizar qualquer método da biblioteca, é apresentado um erro "Referência ao tipo "Control" declara que ele é definido em "System.Web", mas não pode ser encontrado [API]csharp(CS7069)"[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Classe:

```html
BoletoRepository boletoRepository = new BoletoRepository(new GestorMobileContext());
UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository = new UsuarioRepository(new GestorMobileContext());
ClientesRepository clientesRepository = new ClientesRepository(new GestorMobileContext());
LocaisRepository locaisRepository = new LocaisRepository(new GestorMobileContext());

Manager.Entity.Entity.Boletos boleto = new Manager.Entity.Entity.Boletos();
BoletoNet.Boleto boletoNet = new BoletoNet.Boleto();
Clientes cliente = new Clientes();
BoletoNet.BoletoBancario boleto_bancario = new BoletoNet.BoletoBancario();
List<BoletoNet.BoletoBancario> retBoleto = new List<BoletoNet.BoletoBancario>();

boleto = boletoRepository.ConsultEntity(x => x.BolId == codeSlip);
cliente = clientesRepository.ConsultEntity(y => y.EmpId == codeCompany && y.CliCodigo == boleto.CliId);

string clienteNome = cliente.CliNome;
int? parcelasGeradas = (int?)boleto.BolNroparcela;

BoletoNet.Cedente cedente = new BoletoNet.Cedente();
cedente.Nome = boleto.BolNomecedente;

BoletoNet.Sacado sacado = new BoletoNet.Sacado();
sacado.CPFCNPJ = boleto.BolCnpjsacado;
BoletoNet.Endereco enderecoSacado = new BoletoNet.Endereco();
enderecoSacado.CEP = boleto.BolCepsacado.ToString();
enderecoSacado.Cidade = boleto.BolCidadesacado;
enderecoSacado.UF = boleto.BolUfsacado;
sacado.Endereco = enderecoSacado;
sacado.Nome = boleto.BolNomesacado;
clienteNome = boleto.BolNomesacado;

string numeroParcela = Convert.ToString(boleto.BolNroparcela);
string nossoNumero = "";
string sequencial = boleto.BolNossonumero;
    
switch (boleto.BolCodigocedente)
{
case "001": //BB
    nossoNumero = sequencial.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
    boletoNet = new BoletoNet.Boleto(Convert.ToDateTime(boleto.BolDatavencimento), (decimal)boleto.BolValordocumento, boleto.BolCodigocarteira, nossoNumero, cedente);
    boletoNet.Instrucoes = new List<BoletoNet.IInstrucao>() { new BoletoNet.Instrucao_BancoBrasil() { Descricao = boleto.BolMsgtac1 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac2 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac3 } };
    boletoNet.EspecieDocumento = new BoletoNet.EspecieDocumento_BancoBrasil(boleto.BolEspecie);
    break;
case "104": // Caixa
    nossoNumero = sequencial.ToString();
    boletoNet = new BoletoNet.Boleto(Convert.ToDateTime(boleto.BolDatavencimento), (decimal)boleto.BolValordocumento, boleto.BolCodigocarteira, nossoNumero.PadLeft(10, '0'), cedente);
    boletoNet.Instrucoes = new List<BoletoNet.IInstrucao>() { new BoletoNet.Instrucao_Caixa() { Descricao = boleto.BolMsgtac1 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac2 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac3 } };
    boletoNet.EspecieDocumento = new BoletoNet.EspecieDocumento_Caixa(boleto.BolEspecie);
    break;
case "237": // Bradesco
case "036":
case "204":
case "394":
    nossoNumero = boleto.BolCodigocarteira.PadLeft(3, '0') + sequencial.ToString();
    boletoNet = new BoletoNet.Boleto(Convert.ToDateTime(boleto.BolDatavencimento), (decimal)boleto.BolValordocumento, boleto.BolCodigocarteira, nossoNumero, cedente);
    boletoNet.Instrucoes = new List<BoletoNet.IInstrucao>() { new BoletoNet.Instrucao_Bradesco() { Descricao = boleto.BolMsgtac1 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac2 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac3 } };
    boletoNet.EspecieDocumento = new BoletoNet.EspecieDocumento_Bradesco(boleto.BolEspecie);
    break;
case "748": // Sicredi
    nossoNumero = "2" + sequencial.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0');
    boletoNet = new BoletoNet.Boleto(Convert.ToDateTime(boleto.BolDatavencimento), (decimal)boleto.BolValordocumento, boleto.BolCodigocarteira, nossoNumero, cedente);
    boletoNet.Instrucoes = new List<BoletoNet.IInstrucao>() { new BoletoNet.Instrucao_Sicredi() { Descricao = boleto.BolMsgtac1 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac2 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac3 } };
    boletoNet.EspecieDocumento = new BoletoNet.EspecieDocumento_Sicredi(boleto.BolEspecie);
    break;
case "041": //Banrisul
    nossoNumero = sequencial.ToString();
    boletoNet = new BoletoNet.Boleto(Convert.ToDateTime(boleto.BolDatavencimento), (decimal)boleto.BolValordocumento, boleto.BolCodigocarteira, nossoNumero, cedente);
    boletoNet.Instrucoes = new List<BoletoNet.IInstrucao>() { new BoletoNet.Instrucao_Banrisul() { Descricao = boleto.BolMsgtac1 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac2 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac3 } };
    boletoNet.EspecieDocumento = new BoletoNet.EspecieDocumento_Banrisul(boleto.BolEspecie);
    break;
case "033": // Santander
case "351":
case "353":
    nossoNumero = sequencial.ToString();
    boletoNet = new BoletoNet.Boleto(Convert.ToDateTime(boleto.BolDatavencimento), (decimal)boleto.BolValordocumento, boleto.BolCodigocarteira, nossoNumero, cedente);
    boletoNet.Instrucoes = new List<BoletoNet.IInstrucao>() { new BoletoNet.Instrucao_Santander() { Descricao = boleto.BolMsgtac1 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac2 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac3 } };
    boletoNet.EspecieDocumento = new BoletoNet.EspecieDocumento_Santander(boleto.BolEspecie);
    break;
case "031": //Itaú
case "341":
    nossoNumero = sequencial.ToString();
    boletoNet = new BoletoNet.Boleto(Convert.ToDateTime(boleto.BolDatavencimento), (decimal)boleto.BolValordocumento, boleto.BolCodigocarteira, nossoNumero, cedente);
    boletoNet.Instrucoes = new List<BoletoNet.IInstrucao>() { new BoletoNet.Instrucao_Itau() { Descricao = boleto.BolMsgtac1 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac2 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac3 } };
    boletoNet.EspecieDocumento = new BoletoNet.EspecieDocumento_Itau(boleto.BolEspecie);
    break;
case "399": //HSBC
case "168":
    nossoNumero = sequencial.ToString();
    boletoNet = new BoletoNet.Boleto(Convert.ToDateTime(boleto.BolDatavencimento), (decimal)boleto.BolValordocumento, boleto.BolCodigocarteira, nossoNumero, cedente);
    boletoNet.Instrucoes = new List<BoletoNet.IInstrucao>() { new BoletoNet.Instrucao_HSBC() { Descricao = boleto.BolMsgtac1 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac2 + " " + boleto.BolMsgtac3 } };
    boletoNet.EspecieDocumento = new BoletoNet.EspecieDocumento_HSBC(boleto.BolEspecie);
    break;
}

boletoNet.Cedente = cedente;
boletoNet.DataDocumento = (DateTime)boleto.BolDatadocumento;
boletoNet.NumeroDocumento = numeroParcela.PadLeft(6, '0');
boletoNet.Sacado = sacado;
boletoNet.LocalPagamento = "QUALQUER BANCO ATÉ O VENCIMENTO";
        
boleto_bancario.CodigoBanco = Convert.ToInt16(boleto.BolCodigocedente);
boleto_bancario.Boleto = boletoNet;
boleto_bancario.MostrarCodigoCarteira = false;
boleto_bancario.MostrarComprovanteEntrega = false;

boleto_bancario.Boleto.Valida();

retBoleto.Add(boleto_bancario);
string tipoPessoa = boleto.BolTipofj;
int numeroParcelas = (int)parcelasGeradas;

byte[] boletoRet = boleto_bancario.MontaBytesListaBoletosPDF(retBoleto, "Boletos Bancários", "", "Boletos " + clienteNome + ".pdf");
                
return boletoRet;
```

.csproj:

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Boleto.Net" Version="2.1.0.803" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="4.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="4.6.0-preview7.19362.9" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Manager.Entity\Manager.Entity.csproj" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Data\Context\" />
    <Folder Include="Relatorios\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Poderia postar seu os códigos de sua aplicação ? A classe e o arquivo Web.config?

Comment: Como é um projeto .Net Core ele não possui uma web.config, ele cria um arquivo csproj que seria a mesma função que uma web.config

Comment: @EduardodaSilva E você não tentou adicionar a referência ao `System.Web`?

Comment: Já tentei sim @LeandroAngelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ola, você já tentou da uma olhada nesse fork? apesar de ser antigo o post pode ser que te ajude.

https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/issues/496#issuecomment-415422800

Pois pelo que pude intender a boleto.net não suporta .net core

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar com esse fork, já havia visto ele, mas estava utilizando de forma errada.

Instalando apenas pelo Nuget não funcionou, tive que pegar a DLL deste fork e adicionar às referências do meu projeto.

Para gerar um PDF, o gerador do Fork "não funcionou", pois para utilizar o mesmo, necessita de licença comercial, então utilizei a seguinte biblioteca:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDF.Core

Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!